# Import multiple CSV files into mysql

Tags: mysql

I have about 28 csv files and I need to import this into database as 28 tables.
I tried many things but just couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link MYSQL directly to it and upload the information using the following SQL syntax.

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
```

Read more here : [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

[Import CSV file directly into MySQL](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/)

Comment: @ Teez: Thanks for the reply but, I have used this query and it will only take in 1 file. I have around 28 files, I wanted to find a query by which all 28 files would get into 28 tables in a single query

Comment: for 28 tables you need to make a script. if it's one time process then it's better to run query one by one for each table. It will faster then making and running script.

Comment: @ Teez: Thanks a lot. I will try to write a script as that would help me learn more

Answer (score 1):

It's a good solution for Windows-users. Just create a text file "import.bat" with code, after that run it.

```bash
@ECHO off
FOR %%I In (db\*.sql) DO mysqlimport.exe --local -uroot -proot vipamoda %%I
PAUSE
```

More complex code which importing first SQL-structure, then import TXT-data:

```bash
@ECHO off
FOR %%I IN (db\*.sql) DO (
    mysql.exe -uroot -proot vipamoda < %%~dpnI.sql
    mysqlimport.exe --local -uroot -proot vipamoda %%~dpnI.txt
)
PAUSE
```

And dump code for this import code is:

```bash
mysqldump.exe --compact --add-drop-table --tab=db -uroot -proot vipamoda
```